# Am I suffering from divitis?

Tags: html, css

As my code has grown I have noticed that my middle content has been put in an increasing number of tags, specifically divs. Some of these seem duplicate, but when I try to modify any of them, the layout breaks.

This is my stripped code in question:
http://jsfiddle.net/aBbtN/77/

Specifically, my middle content is surrounded like this:

```
    <div id="ie6-container-wrap">
        <div id="container" class="thin_width">
            <div class="full_width">
                <div id="content">               
                    <div class="lft dc2">
                    LEFT SIDEBAR
                    </div>
                    <div class="rgt dc4">
                    RIGHT SIDEBAR
                    </div>
                    <div id="col-main">
                    FINALLY - SOME CONTENT!
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>                    
        </div>
    </div>
```

My question is, is there an opportunity to remove one of those containing divs and still have the layout work correctly?

Comment: As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit **debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion**. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, see the FAQ for guidance.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place to ask.

Comment: Divitis is more so when you replace a table based structure with divs. So instead of table > tr > td, one goes with div > div > div. With your example, it is really hard to say. It is certainly not very lean.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't the right place to ask, but I'll answer anyway.

Yeah, you have divs that you don't need. Instead of using `<div id="ie6-container-wrap">`
use a conditional comment for a different `<head>`

Like

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]><head class="ie6"><![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><head><![endif]-->
```

Or drop IE6 support.

The full width div is not needed, instead set container to width:100%;.

Also, you could use HTML5, and replace sidebar divs with `<aside id="side1"></aside>`

Edit: Here's something you could use and get the same result.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--[if lte IE 6]><head class="ie6"><![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><head><![endif]-->
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
        <div id="container" class="thin_width">
                <div id="content">               
                    <aside class="lft dc2">
                    LEFT SIDEBAR
                    </aside>
                    <aside class="rgt dc4">
                    RIGHT SIDEBAR
                    </aside>
                    <div id="col-main">
                    FINALLY - SOME CONTENT!
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Why do you have a `'full_width'` class on a `<div>`, when `<div>`'s are already full width by default?

Maybe that `<div>` you can remove.